# Don't understand the Garfield's sketch of Feb 9 2017

Tags: jokes, word-play

I read Garfield's comic strip every day but I didn't understand the sketch of February 9, 2017. What does the date of November 8, 1992 refer to ?

[image: Garfield comic strip Feb 9 2017]

Comment: Garfield is remembering the last time he had trouble falling asleep. It was a long time ago, and he remembers the exact date. The joke is about how rare it is that he has a hard time going to sleep.

Comment: So, there is no special event at this date ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: @user3169 Understanding  a language involves understanding how it's used - which involves understanding cultural things about the people who use the language. Understanding humour in another language is a key sign of proficiency in that language. Let's keep this question open.